# Error setting up SFML with Android

Tags: android, c++, sfml

I'm trying to compile SFML onto android, and am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Building-SFML-for-Android). I am installing on Ubuntu 64 bit. I am able to run the cmake command. But when I run make after it, and it is building the headers(or something) I get this error:

```
In file included from /home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/GLCheck.hpp:32:0,
                 from /home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp:30:
/home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp: In member function 'bool sf::Texture::create(unsigned int, unsigned int)':
/home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/GLExtensions.hpp:114:55: error: 'GL_EXT_sRGB' was not declared in this scope
     #define GLEXT_texture_sRGB                        GL_EXT_sRGB
                                                       ^
/home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp:190:31: note: in expansion of macro 'GLEXT_texture_sRGB'
     static bool textureSrgb = GLEXT_texture_sRGB;
                               ^
In file included from /home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp:30:0:
/home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/GLExtensions.hpp:115:55: error: 'GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8_EXT' was not declared in this scope
     #define GLEXT_GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8                     GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8_EXT
                                                       ^
/home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/GLCheck.hpp:51:28: note: in definition of macro 'glCheck'
     #define glCheck(expr) (expr)
                            ^
/home/engineer/Desktop/SFML/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp:213:54: note: in expansion of macro 'GLEXT_GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8'
     glCheck(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (m_sRgb ? GLEXT_GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 : GL_RGBA), m_actualSize.x, m_actualSize.y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL));
                                                      ^
src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeFiles/sfml-graphics.dir/build.make:353: recipe for target 'src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeFiles/sfml-graphics.dir/Texture.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: ** [src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeFiles/sfml-graphics.dir/Texture.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:343: recipe for target 'src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeFiles/sfml-graphics.dir/all' failed
make[1]: ** [src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeFiles/sfml-graphics.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So basically it has a problem with a macro contained in one the cpp files. The make gets to 64% before the error is encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/issues/1079) is being discussed at the moment on SFML's bug tracker.

You can try [this patch](https://github.com/gordonmcshane/SFML/commit/c89d1a987bc8358ea87c56c5aac5f25e4fec8e2d) in the meantime:

```
From c89d1a987bc8358ea87c56c5aac5f25e4fec8e2d Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Gordon McShane <gordonmcshane@gmail.com>
Date: Mon, 4 Apr 2016 11:56:16 -0700
Subject: [PATCH] Fix OpenGL ES compilation issues for Android

-Disable OpenGL ES 3.0 extensions on Android
---
 src/SFML/Graphics/GLExtensions.hpp | 7 ++++++-
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/src/SFML/Graphics/GLExtensions.hpp b/src/SFML/Graphics/GLExtensions.hpp
index b63ea99..3acb6c3 100644
--- a/src/SFML/Graphics/GLExtensions.hpp
+++ b/src/SFML/Graphics/GLExtensions.hpp
@@ -110,9 +110,14 @@
     #define GLEXT_GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING              GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES
     #define GLEXT_GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION    GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION_OES

-    // Core since 3.0 - EXT_sRGB
+#ifdef SFML_SYSTEM_ANDROID
+    #define GLEXT_texture_sRGB                        false
+    #define GLEXT_GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8                     false
+#else
+     // Core since 3.0 - EXT_sRGB
     #define GLEXT_texture_sRGB                        GL_EXT_sRGB
     #define GLEXT_GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8                     GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8_EXT
+#endif

 #else
```